# Coutinuous processing of tail -f output

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file where numbers are continuously appended:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to calculate their mean, also continuously, i.e.:

```
1
1.5
2
2,5
```

I don't want to check file periodically, I want to it in the manner tail -f work - as soon as a line is appended, I perform mean calculations.

Is it possible?

PS Tried `tail -f file.txt | awk '{total+=$0;count+=1;print total/count}'` but it hangs without output

Comment: Your spec is contradictory - tail -f works by checking the file periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to run into buffering issues.  Perhaps a solution that will work for you is:

```
perl -wne 'BEGIN{ $| = 1 } $t += $_; print $t / $. . "\n"; '
```

The $| = 1 turns off buffering. The rest is the same as your awk script.

Comment: why do you think there's a buffering issue?

Comment: @yi_H "hangs without output" very often indicates a buffering issue, but the example awk solution actually works just fine for me.

Comment: Ok, buffered problem was really what I have faced. I have used additional awk after tail -f (need some modifications), which caused problem with buffering. Actually, tail -f is flushing data appropriately. But thanks for your help. What I have ended up is: tail -f source.txt | awk '{...; fflush()}' | awk '{total+=$0;count+=1; print total/count}'

Answer (score -1):

Tcl is great for this kind of event driven programming. Assuming you have a `tclsh` in your PATH:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc calculate_running_mean {chan} {
    gets $chan line
    if {[string is integer -strict $line]} {
        incr ::sum $line
        incr ::count 1
        puts [expr {1.0 * $::sum / $::count}]
    }
}

set filename numbers.txt
set fid [open $filename r]
fileevent $fid readable [list calculate_running_mean $fid]
vwait forever
```

Comment: I think you will find that fileevnt will fire continuously if you try to use it like this - it's really only suitable for reading from a channel like a socket or serial port.